# run hadoop command as sudo

Tags: bash, hadoop

I am trying to run "sudo hadoop namenode -format". I need to run it as sudo, so I cannot change that. But doing so gives the error:

```
sudo: hadoop: command not found
```

I entered the variables in /etc/environment:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0/bin:/home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0/sbin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"
HADOOP_INSTALL="/home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0"
HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME="/home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0"
HADOOP_COMMON_HOME="/home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0"
HADOOP_HDFS_HOME="/home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0"
YARN_HOME="/home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0"
HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR="/home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native"
```

I then created a file under /etc/profile.d,called myenvvars.sh, with the contents:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.library.path=/lib
```

Finally, I wrote the same thing in /etc/bash.bashrc.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.library.path=/lib
```

None of them has worked. Please help!!

Comment: What does `which hadoop` tell you? Maybe you need to `chmod +x /path/to/hadoop`?

Comment: Why do you 'have to' run hadoop as root? In any case, sudo does not copy your environment by default. You need to make the necessary arrangements to set PATH and all the rest of this _for the root_.

Comment: @ShellFish - which hadoop gives the output /home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/hadoop. Doing chmod +x did not change anything.

Comment: @bmargulies - I am trying to install hadoop through a script, to run which I have to use sudo. "sudo hadoop namenode -format" gives that error.

Comment: Run `which hadoop` as root, as bmargulies' post implies.

Comment: "sudo which hadoop" gives nothing.

Comment: You might find 'sudo -E' helpful. http://www.sudo.ws/sudo.man.html.

Comment: Then you need to expand the `PATH` variable in `/root/.bashrc`, simple as that. Or as bmargulies suggests, use the `-E` option, which is safer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the given sudo command will let the hadoop command to be executed with the root user profile, seems your user profile is allowed to execute the sudo as root.

Hope you have made environment varible settings in the profile of your user login and once you use sudo then the root user profile would not get any chance to get to know the setting you have made in your profile.

So the same setting have to be made in the root user profile also before you use the sudo hadoop command.

Else you may very well use the absolute path of the hadoop binary with the sudo command.

Comment: Thank you...I did sudo /home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0/bin/hadoop namenode -format, and it worked!!

Comment: @user3033194, glad it helped you. you may tick best answer if it is much helpful to you..thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You have set environments variables for yourself. By default, when you run sudo, it does not use them, to avoid security exposure something insecure of yours being used by the root user. As per http://www.sudo.ws/sudo.man.html, if you use the `-E` option, it will copy your environment variable settings before running the command. You need to be sure that this won't result in a security compromise.